# Should we worry about conflict when writing shortening url service using hashing

Tags: url, math, url-shortener

thinking to use simple hashing to create a internal used shortening url service. the function i am planing to use is as below

```
    string s = base64Convert(md5(salt: time in million seconds))
    string url = s.substring(0, len: 6)

    Map url to real url
```

there will be 64^6 = 68,719,476,736 possible combinations. should be more than enough for our internal services.

however one thing worry me is, how can i make sure there will not be duplicate url until the 64^6 +1 time hashing?

any thought?

Answer (score 3):

> how can i make sure there will not be duplicate url until the 64^6 +1 time hashing?

Using simple hashing, you can not ensure this property.

Assuming equidistribution of md5, if you have *n* URLs hashed and add one more, then there are *n* possible outcomes how it would collide and 64<sup>6</sup>-*n* how it would not collide. So the chances of a collision for that new element are *n*/64<sup>6</sup>. This value is non-zero even for *n*=1, so the second URL could already collide in theory, even if the chances of this actually happening are extremely low. The more non-colliding URLs you have in your data base, the higher the chances that a new hash will collide with any existing one, until the chance becomes 100% for *n*=64<sup>6</sup>.

If you think about it like this, make sure to keep the [birthday “paradox”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) in mind. If you have a set of *n* URLs you'd like to add, then the chances of *any two* of them colliding are *way* larger than the chances of just the last one colliding with any of the ones you added before. If you [do the math](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2864%5E6%29!%2F%28%2864%5E6%29%5E37000*%2864%5E6-37000%29!%29), you will find that using your scheme, you can expect to hash approximately 37.000 URLs before the chances of a collision between any two of them exceeds 1%.

So you now have to decide whether 1% chance of collision is acceptable, and whether 37.000 URLs is enough for your need. If the probabilistic results don't satisfy you, you can either tweak chances by e.g. using more than 6 digits, or you'll have to implement [collision resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution).